# What would cause %5B0%5D to be added to the url

Tags: php

I am trying to track down why a link to remove a filter is not working on my site. And it appears to be because the links are being changed to have %5B0%5D and other varieties of letters and numbers with % added in

from what I gather this is the serialize function causing this?

Is there anything else that might cause that or is it definitely the serialize function?

Comment: Some characters need to be encoded in order to be in url format, for example the space or #

Comment: %xx where xx is a hexadecímal code is for representing a character. `[0]` is your code saying.

Comment: so not necessarily from the serialize function? maybe there is a space being added that does not need to be?

Comment: posting some complete code would help us see whats going on

Comment: It's very hard to post any code right now because it could be coming from so many different places. But these answers have given me more places to look

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Looks like an Array index to me.  Those are url encoded values that are being added in there.  It will take some work to figure out where.  My suggestion is to step through the code to see what values are building those links.

Comment: its been tough to find so far. But I was mostly looking for serialize. I will look closer now

Answer (score 21):

It's called [**Percent-encoding**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and is used in encoding special characters in the url parameter values.

`[0]` contains special characters so when encoded it gives `%5B0%5D`

where `%5B` represents `[` and `%5D` represent `]`

look for `[0]` in your php .

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you made an url like

```
$url = 'mypage.php?book=$list[0]';
```

instead of

```
$url = "mypage.php?book=$list[0]";
```

Maybe in an indirect manner (template?), otherwise you would have seen it.

Comment: or instead of `$url = "mypage.php?book=".$list[0];` even

Comment: or perhaps: `$url = "mypage.php?book={$list[0]}" `