# PHP - Insert a variable into an array

Tags: php, arrays, variables, attributes

Say we have this array

```
$args = array('responseType' => 'Xml',
    'serverName' => 'vl18278.dinaserver.com',
    'command' => 'Vps_GetUsedSpace',
) ;
```

This array composes an URL to send through cURL. I need to replace `vl18278.dinaserver.com` with a variable $vps, but when I replace it, the URL show a `%5B0%5D` just before the = sign of the attribute serverName:

```
responseType=Xml&serverName%5B0%5D=vl18278.dinaserver.com&command=Vps_GetUsedSpace
```

If I dont replace the `vl18278.dinaserver.com`, the URL is correct.

What is wrong with my code? Why are those %5B0%5D getting into my URL? :(
Thanks in advance.

Complete code:

```
<?php 

$listavps = simplexml_load_file('servers.xml');


foreach ($listavps->servers->server as $vps) {

$urlApi = 'url.php';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$args = array('responseType' => 'Xml',
    'serverName' => 'vl18278.dinaserver.com',
    'command' => 'Vps_GetUsedSpace',
) ;
$args = ( is_array ( $args ) ? http_build_query ( $args, '', '&' ) : $args );
$headers = array();

$handle = curl_init($urlApi);
if( $handle === false ) // error starting curl
{
    $error = '0 - Couldn\'t start curl';
}
else
{

    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_URL, $urlApi );

    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username.':'.$password );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC );

    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60 );
    curl_setopt( $handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4); // set higher if you get a "28 - SSL connection timeout" error

    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, true );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );

    $curlversion = curl_version();
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'PHP '.phpversion().' + Curl '.$curlversion['version'] );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_REFERER, null );

    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false ); // set false if you get a "60 - SSL certificate problem" error

    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $args );
    curl_setopt ( $handle, CURLOPT_POST, true );

    $response = curl_exec ( $handle );
    echo $args;
    if ($response)
    {
        $response = substr( $response,  strpos( $response, "\r\n\r\n" ) + 4 ); // remove http headers
        // parse response


        $responseSimpleXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
        if( $responseSimpleXml === false )
        {
            // invalid xml response
        }
        else
        {
            // parse response
            $errorCode = $responseSimpleXml->response->responseCode ;
            echo $errorCode;
            if( $errorCode == 1000 ) // success
            {
                $usado = $responseSimpleXml->response->data->total_space;
                $capacidad = $responseSimpleXml->response->data->space_limit;
                echo 'Usado: '.$usado.'</br>Total: '.$capacidad.'.';
            }
            else // normal errors
            {
                $errors = $responseSimpleXml->response->errors;
                foreach( $errors->error as $error )
                {
                    // process error
                }
            }
        }


    }
    else // http response code != 200
    {
        $error = curl_errno ( $handle ) . ' - ' . curl_error ( $handle );
    }

    curl_close($handle);
}


}


?>
```

Comment: probably because this array is treated with function urlencode

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16613015/what-would-cause-5b05d-to-be-added-to-the-url

Comment: Please show your _exact_ code.

Comment: @Robert I did not found any urlencode functions in the code. I just put the full code on the question :)

Comment: but for sure you have http_build_query() which uses url encoding

Comment: @Robert I didn't knew that, thanks for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using rawurlencode in the $listavps variable before using it.

```
<?php 

$listavps = simplexml_load_file('servers.xml');

foreach ($listavps->servers->server as $key => $tag) {

$vps = rawurlencode ($tag);

$urlApi = 'url.php';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'pass';
$args = array('responseType' => 'Xml',
    'serverName' => $vps,
    'command' => 'Vps_GetUsedSpace',
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable `$server` must be an array, because, once decoded, `%5B0%5D` is `[0]`.

My guess is to use `$server[0]` instead of `$server` wherever you replace the value. Without the replacement code, it is hard to determine.

Comment: I tried with your suggestion but it remains the same. I just put the full code on the question if you want to look.

Comment: I don't see where you replace `vl18278.dinaserver.com` in your code. For the moment, `echo $args;` gives `responseType=Xml&serverName=vl18278.dinaserver.com&command=Vps_GetUsedSpace` so there doesn't seem to be a problem...

Comment: I need to replace that string, so it show as `$args = array('responseType' => 'Xml',
    'serverName' => $server,
    'command' => 'Vps_GetUsedSpace',
) ;`